# Raven Db Querying

Tags: ravendb

I am using Map Reduce index for query. And I want to select filter by licenceId/licenceIds which may be one or many separated by comma entered in text box

e.g.

```
       L1                (select having LicenseId only L1)

       L1,L2           (select having LicenseId only L1 OR L2)

       L2,L3,L5      (select having LicenseId only L3 OR L3 OR L5)
```

Here is result document:

```
public class GrossSalesByRevenueClass

{

public string LicenseId { get; set; }

public string RevClass { get; set; }

public decimal GrossSales { get; set; }

public decimal NetSales { get; set; }

public int Quantity { get; set; }

public bool NonSales { get; set; }

public DateTime Day { get; set; }

public string DayName { get; set; }

public int Month { get; set; }

public int Quarter { get; set; }

public int Year { get; set; }

}
```

Index is:

```
public class IdxGrossSalesByRevenueClassByDay : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Ticket, GrossSalesByRevenueClass>
{

 public IdxGrossSalesByRevenueClassByDay()

{

Map = docs => from doc in docs
from c in doc.Coversfrom t in c.TicketItems
 select new
{
LicenseId = doc.LicenseId,
RevClass = t.RevenueClass,
GrossSales = t.TicketItemGross,
NetSales = t.NetPrice,
Quantity = t.Quantity,
NonSales = t.IsNonSales,
Day = doc.TicketDate.Date,
DayName = doc.TicketDate.ToString("ddd")
};

 Reduce = result => from r in result
 group r by new { r.NonSales, r.RevClass, r.Day, r.LicenseId } into g
 select new
{
LicenseId = g.Key.LicenseId,
RevClass = g.Key.RevClass,
GrossSales = g.Sum(x => x.GrossSales),
NetSales = g.Sum(x => x.NetSales),
Quantity = g.Sum(x => x.Quantity),
NonSales = g.Key.NonSales,
Day = g.Key.Day,
DayName = g.Select(x => x.DayName).FirstOrDefault(),
};

}

}
```

And I am querying like following:

```
GrossSalesByRevenueClassCollection = session.Query<GrossSalesByRevenueClass, IdxGrossSalesByRevenueClassByDay>()

                    .TransformWith<GrossSalesByRevenueClassTransformer, GrossSalesByRevenueClass>()

                    .Where(x => x.Day >= d1 && x.Day <= d2 && (?????))
```

In place of `(?????)`  there should be License id list `(L1 OR L2)`

I tried `Contains()` in where but not working for me please tell me how do I query an index

for such a requirement.

Answer (score 1):

something like this

```
var licenses = userLicenses.Split(",");

GrossSalesByRevenueClassCollection = session.Query<GrossSalesByRevenueClass, IdxGrossSalesByRevenueClassByDay>()
                    .Where(x => x.Day >= d1 && x.Day <= d2 && x.LicenseId.In(licenses))
```